# Invariant subspace associated with a complex eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space over the reals and $T:E\to E$ a linear operator. Suppose that $\mu=re^{i\theta}$ is a eigenvalue of $T$ with $r>0$. How can one find two vector $z_1,z_2\in E$ such that if $R_\theta$ is the rotation by $\theta$ in the plane $P\subset E$ spanned by $z_1,z_2$, then $$T_{|P}z=r R_\theta z$$

where $T_{|P}$ is the restriction of $T$ to $P$ and $z\in P$ can be identified with $z_1+iz_2=(z_1,z_2)$.

Remark: If $E$ is finite dimensional, this is the same as real Jordan decomposition, so my problem really is in infinite dimensional spaces. Maybe we need to add some hypothesis, like $T$ being compact or something like that, if so please feel free to add.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the complexification $T_\mathbb{C} \colon E_\mathbb{C} \to E_\mathbb{C}$, since $T_\mathbb{C}$ is a real operator, for an eigenvector $z$ to the eigenvalue $\mu$, you have $T_\mathbb{C}(\overline{z}) = \overline{\mu}\cdot\overline{z}$, i.e. $\overline{z}$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\overline{\mu}$.

Thus $(\overline{\mu}I - T_\mathbb{C})\circ(\mu I-T_\mathbb{C})$ vanishes on $\operatorname{span} \{z,\, \overline{z}\} = \operatorname{span} \{\operatorname{Re} z,\, \operatorname{Im} z\} \subset E_\mathbb{C}$.

Now, $(\overline{\mu}I - T_\mathbb{C})\circ(\mu I-T_\mathbb{C}) = r^2 I - 2r\cos\theta\cdot T_\mathbb{C} + {T_\mathbb{C}}^2$ is a real operator since $T_\mathbb{C}$ is one, hence $r^2 I - 2r\cos\theta\cdot T + T^2$ vanishes on $\operatorname{span} \{\operatorname{Re} z,\, \operatorname{Im} z\} \subset E$.

So the existence of $z_1,\,z_2$ spanning a plane on which $T$ acts by $r\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ is assured.

In simple cases, that may even give a practical way to find $z_1,\, z_2$.

Comment: Sorry, but when you say that $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a real operator, what do you want to mean?

Comment: That means that for the conjugation on $E_\mathbb{C}$, we have $T_\mathbb{C}(\overline{z}) = \overline{T(z)}$ for all $z \in E_\mathbb{C}$. A model is $E_\mathbb{C} = E\times E$ (as a real space), $i\cdot(z,\,w) = (-w,\,z)$ is how it is made a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, $\overline{(z,\,w)} = (z,\, -w)$; $T_\mathbb{C}(z,w) = (Tz,\,Tw)$ is the complexification of $T$ (modelling $T(z+iw) = Tz + i\cdot Tw$).

Comment: Ok thank you, now I got it.

Comment: @Tomás At that point, let me stress that the above requires that $\mu$ be an eigenvalue, and not any old spectral value. For compact operators, all nonzero spectral values are of course eigenvalues, so then everything is fine.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any book to suggest me?

Comment: Depends on what for. For general theory, I like Rudin (Functional Analysis). If you're interested in topological vector spaces without getting too weird, Trèves (Topological Vector Spaces) and Meise/Vogt (Introduction to Functional Analysis), if you want also weird, Köthe (Linear Topological Spaces). If you're more interested in the Sobolev space thingy, umm, I think Pedersen (Analysis Now) treats them not badly, but I may misremember that, that wasn't my thing.